# discord.js bot reports [object object] when trying to send an embed

Tags: javascript, embed, discord, discord.js

I am coding a bot that has to send embeds. But when the embed is sent, the bot says `[object Object]`.

---

Code for Embed:

```
const embed9 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("1h Until Convoy - Sim1")
            .setURL("https://www.scanialtd.com/")
            .setColor(16571139)
            .setDescription("There is 1 hour untill the convoy on Simulation 1 in ETS2. Get ready to join by launching ETS2 and logging on to Simulation 1. Join the Convoy Lounge while you wait.")
            .setFooter("Created by ScaniaLTD Convoy Announcements Bot, https://www.scanialtd.com/uploads/6/3/4/9/63493649/published/logo_3.png")
            .setImage("http://i.imgur.com/yVpymuV.png")
            .setThumbnail("https://www.scanialtd.com/uploads/6/3/4/9/63493649/published/logo_3.png")
            .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send('@ConvoyReminders' + {embed9})
```

Comment: Simplified title and question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatenating a string and an object with embed9 inside.

To mention a person you need to add the `@<Username>` in `.setDescription`. Then you can just do `message.channel.send(embed9)`

Answer (score 0):

Because you try send stirng + embed object in 1 args. 
And you can`t mention peaple with their `name + @` you need use `user.id` for this, like `<@213123131321>` or `<@&1232312123132>` for roles.

Right way:

```
const embed9 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("1h Until Convoy - Sim1")
            .setURL("https://www.scanialtd.com/")
            .setColor(16571139)
            .setDescription("There is 1 hour untill the convoy on Simulation 1 in ETS2. Get ready to join by launching ETS2 and logging on to Simulation 1. Join the Convoy Lounge while you wait.")
            .setFooter("Created by ScaniaLTD Convoy Announcements Bot, https://www.scanialtd.com/uploads/6/3/4/9/63493649/published/logo_3.png")
            .setImage("http://i.imgur.com/yVpymuV.png")
            .setThumbnail("https://www.scanialtd.com/uploads/6/3/4/9/63493649/published/logo_3.png")
            .setTimestamp()

        message.channel.send('@ConvoyReminders', embed9)
```